# How We can remove the Keyboard listener from RN 0.66 as removeListener() method is deprecated?

Tags: react-native

I faced this problem when updated my React Native version. I checked the documentation it says **removeListener** is deprecated.

```
useEffect(() => {

        Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", keyboardDidShow);
        Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", keyboardDidHide);


        return () => {
            Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardDidShow", keyboardDidShow);
            Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardDidHide", keyboardDidHide);
        };




    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this like this:

```
useEffect(() => {


       const unsubscribe_KeyboardDidShow = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", keyboardDidShow);
        const unsubscribe_keyboardDidHide = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", keyboardDidHide);

    
        return () => {
            
           unsubscribe_KeyboardDidShow.remove();
           unsubscribe_keyboardDidHide.remove();

        };

    }, []);
```

Faced this when updated my React Native version.